# Include Twig templates with Jquery 'on change' / only partially working

Tags: jquery, twig, include, symfony4

Almost everything works but I don't know why the second include is only partially working.

I explain myself =>

I have a twig template which contains a form row named "type" :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Supports pédagogiques - {{ parent() }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">

    {{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}} ) }}

        <div class="row justify-content-center">

            <div class="col-md-10 alert alert-light text-center">

                <h1>Nouveau contenu</h1>
                <hr>

                {{form_row((form.type), {'id': 'type'}) }}

                <div class="form_container">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

This row provides a choice of 3 'options' as you can see in the ContentType.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Content;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\UrlType;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType;

class ContentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'placeholder' => 'Choisissez un type de contenu',
                'label' => 'Type de contenu',
                'choices'  => array(
                    'Tutoriel vidéo' => 'Tutoriel',
                    'Autre vidéo' => 'Vidéo',
                    'Support PDF' => 'Support PDF'
                ),
            ))
            ->add('title', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Titre'
                ))
            ->add('link', UrlType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Lien de la vidéo (copier l\'URL de la page)'
                ))
            ->add('description', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Description du contenu'
                ))
            ->add('pdfFile', VichFileType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Uploader le PDF'
                ))
            // ->add('created_at')
            // ->add('user')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Content::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and I want the rest of the form to be include depending on the option choosed (one form for PDF and another one for Tutoriel and Video) so I added some Jquery :

```
{% block javascripts %}
<script>

    $("#type").on('change', function () {
        var type = $(this).val();
        if (type == 'Support PDF') {
            $('.form_container').html(`{% include 'form/pdf.html.twig' %}`);
        } else {
            $('.form_container').html(`{% include 'form/video.html.twig' %}`);
        }
    });

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's form/pdf.html.twig :

```
{{form_row(form.title)}}
{{form_row(form.description)}}
{{form_row(form.pdfFile)}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Ajouter le PDF</button>
```

And here's form/video.html.twig :

```
{{form_row(form.title)}}
{{form_row(form.description)}}
{{form_row(form.link)}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Ajouter la vidéo</button>
```

When 'Support PDF' is selected, everythings fine, the complete form is include.
But when one of the 2 others is selected, video.html.twig is only partially include :

To be more precise : {{form_row(form.title)}} and {{form_row(form.description)}} aren't included.

I have only :

```
{{form_row(form.pdfFile)}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Ajouter le PDF</button>.
```

I can't explain this issue...

Comment: What about using ajax to render the forms and then updating your UI instead of having the forms directly in your source code like that?.

Comment: @DarkBee, I tried to do it as you suggested but it doesn't work for me. I have an issue when updating my UI. I keep your suggestion and will retry later.

Comment: @Emma, I added spaces as you suggested but it didn't solve my problem. However, I'll keep this in mind and will put spaces everytime to be sure. Thanks !